# android, cant resolve getListAdapter and setOnItemLongClickListener inside fragment

Tags: android, fragment, syntax-error

In here I am trying to make `OnItemLongClick`, I tried doing it in `ListActivity` before and that's working.
Now I am trying to make one inside a Fragment, but I get an error here and there, I need some advice/suggestion/answer to solve the error, or the correct way to implement the method.

In the ListActivity (working):

```
public class ViewData extends ListActivity implements OnItemLongClickListener {

//init controller
private DBDataSource dataSource;

//init arraylist
private ArrayList<Barang> values;
private Button delButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.viewdata);
      dataSource = new DBDataSource(this);
      // open controller
      dataSource.open();

      // get values
      values = dataSource.getAllBarang();

      // insert data to array adapter
      ArrayAdapter<Barang> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Barang>(this,
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

      // set adapter in list
      setListAdapter(adapter);

      // listview for set onItemLongClickListener
      ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
      lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

}

//if user longclick
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int pos,
        final long id) {

    //tampilkan alert dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_view);
    dialog.setTitle("Pilih Aksi");
    dialog.show();
    final Barang b = (Barang) getListAdapter().getItem(pos);
    delButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_delete_data);


    //apabila tombol delete di klik
    delButton.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Delete barang
                    dataSource.deleteBarang(b.getId());
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            }
            );

    return true;

}
}
```

The Fragment version (still giving an error) :

```
public class Menu_Riwayat extends Fragment {
//init controller
private DBDataSource dataSource;

//init arraylist
private ArrayList<Investasi_DB> values;

static ListView lv;
private Button button_hapus;
static LinearLayout mLinear;

@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mLinear = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewdata, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) mLinear.findViewById(R.id.list);
    dataSource = new DBDataSource(getActivity());
    // open controller
    dataSource.open();

    // get values
    values = dataSource.getAllInvestasi_DB();

    // insert data to array adapter
    ArrayAdapter<Investasi_DB> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Investasi_DB>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    // set adapter in list
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    return mLinear;
    // ERROR IN THIS PART BELOW, not sure what to change "this" with
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int pos,
                               final long id) {
    //tampilkan alert dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_view);
    dialog.setTitle("Pilihan");
    dialog.show();

    // ERROR IN THIS PART BELOW, not sure how to implement "getListAdapter()" inside fragment
    final Investasi_DB b = (Investasi_DB) getListAdapter().getItem(pos);
    button_hapus = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_hapus);
    button_hapus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dataSource.deleteInvestasi_DB(b.getId());
            dialog.dismiss();
            getActivity().finish();
             // ERROR IN THIS PART BELOW, the "getIntent()" part
            startActivity(getIntent());

        }
    });

    return true;
}
}
```

I need help to solve the error (correct way to implement it):
`getListAdapter()`, `getIntent()`, and `this` in `lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

EDITED PART AFTER SOME SUGGESTION :
so now i make it like this

```
public class Menu_Riwayat extends Fragment {
//inisialisasi kontroller
private DBDataSource dataSource;

//inisialisasi arraylist
private ArrayList<Investasi_DB> values;

static ListView lv;
private Button button_hapus;
static LinearLayout mLinear;

@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mLinear = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewdata, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) mLinear.findViewById(R.id.list);
    dataSource = new DBDataSource(getActivity());
    // buka kontroller
    dataSource.open();

    // ambil semua data barang
    values = dataSource.getAllInvestasi_DB();

    // masukkan data barang ke array adapter
    ArrayAdapter<Investasi_DB> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Investasi_DB>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    // set adapter pada list
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    //lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_view);
            dialog.setTitle("Pilihan");
            dialog.show();

            final Investasi_DB b = (Investasi_DB) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            button_hapus = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_hapus);
            button_hapus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dataSource.deleteInvestasi_DB(b.getId());
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return mLinear;
}
```

its working, but the apps close itself after i click the button (i think because of getActivity().finish();), any idea about that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need help to solve the error (correct way to implement it):
>   getListAdapter(), getIntent(), and this in
>   lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

if with `this` you want to access a `Context`, you can use `getActivity()`. `Fragment` is not a `Context`

In `setOnItemClickListener(this);`, `this` refers to the current instance. With that line you are implying that `this` is also implementing the `OnItemClickListener` interface. Which is not true. You need yo add `implement OnItemClickListener` to your `Fragment` class.

```
getListAdapter():
```

instead of `getListAdapter()` you can use the ListView to retrieve the item at position, since you are already keeping a reference as member. Change

```
final Investasi_DB b = (Investasi_DB) getListAdapter().getItem(pos);
```

with

```
 final Investasi_DB b = (Investasi_DB) lv.getItemAtPosition(pos);
```

why do you need this line `startActivity(getIntent());`?

Comment: oh superb, i realize where i am wrong at, i try implementing the setOnItemClickListener(this); into the onCreateVIew method, and fix the code like what u suggest, its working now, the startActivity(getIntent()); is so that the apps didnt close itself after i click the button. when i erase the line, after i click the button, the apps close it self, any idea what should i do with that problem ?

Comment: why do you have `getActivity().finish();`? If you have only one Activity you are experiencing the correct behaviour

Comment: the button is for deleting data from sqlite, so if i not using getActivity().finish(); the data in listview still not erased (even tho its erased already in database), i am using getActivity().finish(); and getIntent so the interface will be dynamic ( after delete data in listview, the deleted data will instantly gone ). please tell me if its not a good way to do it

Comment: you have to remove the item at position from the Adapter too. You don't have to call finish() on the Activity. Check the documentation of ArrayAdapter to see which method you have to use to remove items. If I were in you I would look into the CursorAdapter

Comment: sorry to bother you again, tried looking into CursorAdapter but not really understand about it, so just one foolish question, is it possible to do what i want with the current code ?

Comment: yes it is possible. The `CursorAdapter` is nice because handles directly with the Cursor, and requery automatically the ContentProvide (if you have one) in case you make changes to  your database.